# Why is it my user interface not showing up on screen?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom, firebaseui

have a problem. Am working on a small project based on react and firebase. My design isn't showing up, even when I refresh the browser, it shows the design for a couple of seconds, then shows a white screen. I have tried to stop the server and re-run it again and again but nothing. It's being two days I've been looking for a solution on my own. Please help me!!

here is my App.js

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

/* firebase user interface buttons auth buttons */
  const uiConfig = {
    sigInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccess: () => false,
    },
  };

/* Verifying is a user has signed in or up */
  const authListener = () => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser('');
      }
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>

{/* verifying if user is signed in or up */}
      { user ? (
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      ):(
        <>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Navbar />
              <SearchComponent />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signin">
              <Signin uiConfig={uiConfig}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signup">
              <Signup uiConfig={uiConfig} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </>
      )}
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I am not getting what's the problem because i have copy pasted your code and everything works fine for me

Comment: Did you check your browser console to see if there is something wrong?

Comment: Actually I checked the console but nothing